# MAUI WebView small resolution on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, maui

I'm developing a simple webapp with Xamarin/MAUI.
If I build it on iOS it works fine, but on Android (both emulator and two different devices) the page content is displayed as if the screen was 400px.

If I remove `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.5, initial-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no">` from the header of my website it's technically correct, but not as I intended.
Is there a way to maintain the header and display the page correctly on Android?

Thanks!

Comment: Unclear what you are saying is wrong. Content becomes too large? Too small? "If I remove ...". Are you saying that without that line, it does display what it "should" ("technically correct"), though not what you want? I mean, is the problem that Android ignores that line? If you display the page in an Android browser, does it behave the same as in Maui WebView? Bottom line: if that line isn't supported in Android, then you'll probably have to redesign your website so it looks the way you want, without using that unsupported feature.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not english so it's difficult to me to explain.
The website works correctly in regular browser like Chrome, Firefox (both on iOS and Android) and Safari. I created a simple app with a webview, if I build in iOS the content is visualized correctly (just like all other browser)
If I build the same app on Android the content is showed as if the screen is 400px
If i create a box of 400px on the html, on the Android app it fills everything horizzontally

Recap
-Browser on iOS: ok
-Browser on Android: ok
-MAUI app on iOS: ok
-MAUI app on Android: NO

Hope that explain it better

Comment: I asked several questions. Please attempt to answer each one. I'll add more: does it show up larger, as if the scale command was not there? Is the width of the screen 800 DIPs (Device-Independent Pixels, about 1/160 inch each)? Or width in pixels, and what Pixel Density does device say it has?